# How to display firstname in a textfield when original string is surname, firstname? React/Spfx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spfx

I want to simple extract the firstname from a string. The Firstname and lastname is separated by a comma.

I understand it will involve an inbuilt function to find the comma, then extract all the string AFTER the comma.

I want it to be displayed in a text field.

```
 public _getUser() { //getUser sets the state for multiple properties of the user. 

    sp.web.currentUser.get().then((user) => {

      this.setState({
        CurrentUserTitle: user.Title,
        ExtractedFirstName:
```

The code above is what I'm using to get the logged in User. I imagine a function will have to be created but what would I put in the function, to then set to state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first name and last name are in the following shape: `firstName,lastName`, you can just split the string on a comma and extract the first part of the resulting array:

```
this.setState({
  // ...
  ExtractedFirstName: firstNameAndLastNameCombined.split(',')[0]
```

If the combination of first name and last name has some whitespace, you can also trim the result:

```
this.setState({
  // ...
  ExtractedFirstName: firstNameAndLastNameCombined.split(',')[0].trim()
```

Here's an example for both:

```js
const firstNameAndLastNameCombined = 'Cool,Example';

console.log(
  firstNameAndLastNameCombined.split(',')[0]
) // Cool

const firstNameAndLastNameCombinedWithSpace = '  Cool  ,   Example   ';

console.log(
  firstNameAndLastNameCombinedWithSpace.split(',')[0].trim()
) // Cool
```